# Jquery get file and render depending on extension

Tags: jquery, file, mime-types

I have a list of links to files, images, videos etc.

Im trying to create a jquery function to loop over the list of links and render the files.
If the file is a png to render it as an img, if it is a mp4 to render it as a video.

I have created the following jquery which will get the file src and put it into an img tag which works.

```
$(a).each(function(i, a) {
   href = $(a).attr('href');
   $(a).replaceWith('<img src="' + href + '">');
});
```

But I need to check the extension and either put it in an img tag or video tag. So I have tried the following jquery but it does not work.

```
$(a).each(function(i, a) {
   href = $(a).attr('href');
   var extension = href.substr( (file.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
     switch(extension) {
       case 'png':
          $(a).replaceWith('<img src="' + href + '">');
       break;                         
       case 'mp4':
          $(a).replaceWith('<video src="' + href + '">');
       break;
     }
});
```

How can I get the file extension and if it is a video type put the src in a video tag instead of an img tag?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` method of jquery to split your `href` from `.` and then use `extension[1]` this will give either `png,mp4..etc` then just compare it inside switch statement and show them .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var a = $("a")
$(a).each(function(i, a) {
  href = $(this).attr('href');
  //spilt href from `.` and get 1 position value
  var extension = href.split(".")[1];
  console.log(extension)
  switch (extension) {
    case 'png':
      $(a).replaceWith('<img src="' + href + '" alt="' + href + '">');
      break;
    case 'mp4':
      $(a).replaceWith('<video width = "200" height = "200" controls><source src = "' + href + '" type = "video/mp4"></video>');
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="image1.png"></a>
<a href="image2.png"></a>

<a href="video.mp4"></a>
<a href="video1.mp4"></a>
<a href="image3.png"></a>
```